# Using ArcGIS python window to change definition query on layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.4, python-window

I post a very simple script to the python window to change the definition query on a layer.  I save the map and load a new template then try to run the query again and nothing happens.  I have recently upgraded to 10.4 and when running 10.3 I never had this kind of issue.  I have tried deleting all variables at the end of the script.  Nothing works.  It will only run one time and I have to close out the ArcMap session before it will work again.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve ArcPy/Python we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  You say "I post a very simple script" so I think that script should be included in this question.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to the same issue with my script and all I had to do was add:

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
```

and I haven't had to exit/re-enter since.